# Should we unsubscribe from ngxs Selector?

Tags: angular, ngxs

I'm using ngxs State management. Do I need to unsubscribe from Selectors or is this handled by ngxs?

```
@Select(list)list$!: Observable<any>;

this.list$.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Yes you should. This is one of the ways you can unsubscribe: https://alligator.io/angular/takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the first example you can use in combination with the [Async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). The Async pipe will unsubscribe for you:

In your `ts` file:

```
@Select(list) list: Observable<any>;
```

In your `html` file:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list | async">
</ng-container>
<!-- this will unsub automatically -->
```

However, when you want to use the actual subscribe method, you will need to unsubscribe manually. Best way to do that is using `takeUntil`:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private destroy: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.select(SomeState).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(value => {
      this.someValue = value;
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy.next(true);
    this.destroy.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You can use `pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))` for every subscription in your component without the need to manually add `unsubscribe()` for every one of them.

Comment: I agree with Scuba Kay. It's exactly what we do in our enterprise project.

Answer (score 3):

The Async Pipe solution is usually the best.

Depending on your use case, you can also use the **first()** operator.

```
observable.pipe(first()).subscribe(...)
```

It is shorter than the takeUntil approach and you don't need any unsubscribe.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html

Beware: This will return a value and unsubscribe. So it can be used if you need a current value from the store and then do something with it. Don't use it to display something on the GUI - it will only show the first change :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you subscribe manually in the component then you need to unsubscribe.

Best to avoid that if possible and subscribe in the component template using the `async` pipe.